# Variables for previous/next post buttons in twentyfourteen

Tags: php, wordpress

I think this should be very easy, but I cannot find any support for this online.

In single.php, in order to navigate forward and backward through posts the twentyfourteen theme uses the function:

```
twentyfourteen_post_nav();
```

I want to navigate only through posts in the same category as the current post, something like:

```
twentyfourteen_post_nav($taxonomy='category');
```

But nothing is working?? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In twenty fourteen, the default `single.php` uses [get_adjacent_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) but sets the default values inside of `inc/template_tags.php`

The full solution is going to require some more specific thinking about acceptable ways to modify `inc/template_tags.php`.  For example: what happens if a post has multiple categories?

Here is some code for you to put in your `inc/template_tags.php`.  Notice that I've replaced the first `false` value with `true` in both calls to `get_adjacent_post()`. These are the only two changes.

```
function twentyfourteen_post_nav() {
    $category_zero = get_the_category();
    // Don't print empty markup if there's nowhere to navigate.
    $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( true, '', true );
    $next     = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false );
```

And that's it for the simple version of your problem!